# In a .NET web app, how do I get functions to work with RDLC?

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I have a web application that uses RDLC to format reports in both Excel and PDF. The values appear fine when I insert them directly from a DataSet, but when I use any sort of function other than First(), the value shows "#Error" in PDF and "#VALUE!" in Excel. This includes using & to concentate two strings.

For example, my DataSet has fields named LastName and FirstName. Using either field name by itself works, but something like LastName & ", " & FirstName, or Trim(LastName), returns the error value.

Short of rewriting every report to do all of the formatting/calculations in the back-end C# code and passing the results into the data set, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: does the report render the expressions ok, but ONLY export to Excel or PDF show this issue?

Comment: How can I tell? I do know that the field values themselves are valid.

Comment: You are confusing me now. Either the report renders and you can view it or you can't. If you can't view the report, then by any reasonable logic, it certainly not going to export to excel or PDF then right? I mean, at least check/determine/try/test if the report works LONG before you do something complex like exporting the report to Excel or a pdf then, right??? So, run the report and view it. If the report does not work, then it would be beyond silly to NOW and THEN ask why can't I export a broken not working report to Excel or PDF. We require a working report before testing some exporting

Comment: Let me put it this way.
I have a DataSet named "UserData"; it contains two string fields named "LastName" and "FirstName".
If I have a text box and assign it field UserData.FirstName, and another text box and assign it UserData.LastName, the report is generated and the values appear correctly.
However, if I have a text box and assign it the expression UserData.LastName & ", " & UserData.FirstName, the report is still generated, but it appears as "#Error" (PDF) or "#VALUE!" (Excel).

Comment: Right, but you still not clear if the report renders and displays correclty. At this point in time this has ZERO to do with Excel or a PDF. If the report does not render, then no hope of Excel or PDF going to work. On the other hand, if the report renders and excel and pdf does not, then  you have a valid point which we can pursue. So, if the report does not render correctly, then ZERO hope exists in regards to Excel and PDF, and we will leave the Excel and PDF for another day and down the road to troubleshoot, right? So either Excel and PDF's are relevant to this question, or they are not.

Comment: Ok, I read your comment close! So yes, the report looks good, renders ok, it is ONLY upon export to Excel or pdf does the report fail. So, we have a working report.

Comment: So, to be clear: report renders the value(s) ok, it only PDF that you get "error", and for Excel you get "value". But, previewing the report, the values show fine.

Comment: Well,  I see we have someone that does not grasp the process of troubeshooting here. You see, there is the report rendering system, and THEN there is a system that renders the execl output, and also a differnt routine/code that renders the PDF output. So, THAT is why I am asking about if the report renders correctly BEFORE we attempt to export say as excel. we have to determine if the report rendering works FIRST, and THEN and ONLY then do we move on to the 2nd part. There are reports that will render, but fail on export to Excel/pdf. thus, we NEED to FIRST determine if report works.